# List<List<String>> vs. String[][]

Tags: java, performance, math, matrix, processing-efficiency

I'm looking to create a 2D String 'matrix' object in Java. My two goals with this are for efficiency and code simplicity.

I've heard that using an ArrayList is quite a bit more efficient than a String[][]. Firstly, I'm wondering if that's true, and if so, how much more efficient?

The other thing is that I must have the ability to add columns and rows to the 'matrix'. I was able to develop some efficient algorithms for adding rows and columns to a String[][]. I'm curious to know if it would be worth it to develop algorithms to manipulate a 2D List in this way - would there be a significant performance improvement?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Efficiency in what opearations? Keep in mind each container has advantages over the other in just few operations.

Comment: I'm most concerned with the performance when adding rows and columns. I will also be performing various operations on individual columns and rows such as reversing the characters in the strings and counting the characters in each string of a row and/or column. Sorry if that sounds a little bit vague...

Comment: If your columns could have a fixed maximum size (sounds reasonable) the array should be faster, since you could change the values by indexes, which is usually faster. If this is not the case, you will need lists, since array would't allow this flexibility.

Comment: I've been playing around with a Matrix data structure, you might find it useful: https://github.com/mplatvoet/matrix

Comment: @Gnqz thanks! That's an interesting suggestion.

Comment: @M Platvoet Thanks! I'll have to look into it a little bit more, but it looks great!

Comment: If adding columns and rows is a very common operation you expect then a third option that might be worth investigating is a `Map<Coordinate, String>`.  This means you don't have to reallocate arrays/lists.   Memory performance will be poorer, however, and it'll need some thorough investigation to see if it really helps out in your situation or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the simple answer: Direct array operations will be faster since you avoid the overhead of the general purpose classes. You can even gain more performance by leveraging the [Unsafe](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/sun/misc/Unsafe.java) instance (non public API) for direct array access.

And for the opinion part:  I would rather look at how things can be executed concurrently or distributed amongst different systems if performance is that important. In that case I would prefer avoiding using arrays directly since that would be hard to maintain. But of course it all depends on your specific use case.

So, like with all performance related questions, do some measurements for your specific use case and decide for yourself what works best for you.

And like I said in the comments, I have fiddled around with own [Matrix](https://github.com/mplatvoet/matrix) implementation which have two specialised Map implementations ([CompactArrayMap](https://github.com/mplatvoet/matrix/blob/master/src/main/java/nl/mplatvoet/collections/map/CompactArrayMap.java) and [DirectArrayMap](https://github.com/mplatvoet/matrix/blob/master/src/main/java/nl/mplatvoet/collections/map/DirectArrayMap.java)) which are both int to key mappings on the keys natural order, so much like an array but with map functionality.

Answer (score 3):

`List` is an interface.  Given this interface, you can use different implementation such as `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, etc

So your question perhaps should be rephrased as

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> vs String[][]
```

`ArrayList` is a list implemented using an array.  It has methods that let you handle element in a specific position:

```
void add(int index, E element);
E    get(int index);
```

I used to think `ArrayList` is almost as fast as an array, but I guess
the actual usage would determine the actual performance difference.  Below I add 
some results from an anecdotal experiment that shows that array is
faster than `ArrayList`, especially during the population of the 2-D matrix. 
The access times of the two seem to be on par with each other.

`ArrayList` gives you some advantage, such as you don't have to know
the size in advance.  Having that said, however, if I am sure that what I need is an array and never a generic list (for example, as you said, for matrix computation), then I may use an array for the more succinct syntax.

```
String s1 = array[i][j];
array[i][j] = s1;
```

Versus

```
String s2 = list.get(j).get(i);
list.get(j).add(i, s2);
```

For more information distinguishing the interface from its implementation, you can refer to this tutorial by Oracle/Sun:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/list.html

**Anecdotal Experiment**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class ArrayListVsString {

    private static final int NUM_TESTS = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<String>>  list;
        String[][]          array; 
        int height  = 500;
        int width   = 1000;
        String __ = "    "; // indent
        for (int n=0; n<NUM_TESTS; n++) {
            System.out.format("Testing 2D matrix of %dx%d: Test %d%n"
                    , height, width, n);
            /*
             * Time to populate the matrices
             */
            long startTime = System.nanoTime();
            // array
            String subTestArray = "2-D array";
            array = new String[width][height];
            for (int i=0; i<width; i++) {
                for (int j=0; j<height; j++) {
                    array[i][j] = getRandomString();
                }
            }
            startTime 
                = logElapsedTime(startTime
                                , __ + "creating matrix as " 
                                     + subTestArray);
            // array-list
            String subTestList = "2-D array-list";
            list = new ArrayList<>(height);
            for (int j=0; j<height; j++) {
                List<String> row = new ArrayList<>(width);
                list.add(j, row);
                for (int i=0; i<width; i++) {
                    String element = getRandomString();
                    list.get(j).add(i, element);
                }
            }
            startTime 
                = logElapsedTime(startTime
                            , __ + "creating matrix as " 
                                 + subTestList);

            int hash = 0;
            /*
             * Time to do a full walk through all the elements
             */
            // array
            for (int i=0; i<width; i++) {
                for (int j=0; j<height; j++) {
                    hash += (array[i][j]).hashCode();
                }
            }
            startTime 
                = logElapsedTime(startTime
                                , __ + "full walk of matrix as" 
                                     + subTestArray);

            // array-list
            for (int j=0; j<height; j++) {
                for (int i=0; i<width; i++) {
                    hash += list.get(j).get(i).hashCode();
                }
            }
            startTime 
                = logElapsedTime(startTime
                                , __ + "full walk of matrix as "
                                     + subTestList);
            list = null;

        }

    }

    private static Random random = new Random();

    private static String getRandomString() {
        return String.valueOf(random.nextInt());
    }

    private static long logElapsedTime(long startTimeNano
            , String action) {
        long elapsedTimeNano = System.nanoTime() - startTimeNano;
        System.out.format("%s took %,d ms%n"
                    , action, elapsedTimeNano/1000000);

        return System.nanoTime();
    }
}
```

**Results**

```
Testing 2D matrix of 500x1000: Test 0
    creating matrix as 2-D array took 117 ms
    creating matrix as 2-D array-list took 232 ms
    full walk of matrix as2-D array took 25 ms
    full walk of matrix as 2-D array-list took 31 ms
Testing 2D matrix of 500x1000: Test 1
    creating matrix as 2-D array took 65 ms
    creating matrix as 2-D array-list took 186 ms
    full walk of matrix as2-D array took 20 ms
    full walk of matrix as 2-D array-list took 30 ms
Testing 2D matrix of 500x1000: Test 2
    creating matrix as 2-D array took 61 ms
    creating matrix as 2-D array-list took 60 ms
    full walk of matrix as2-D array took 14 ms
    full walk of matrix as 2-D array-list took 15 ms
Testing 2D matrix of 500x1000: Test 3
    creating matrix as 2-D array took 66 ms
    creating matrix as 2-D array-list took 358 ms
    full walk of matrix as2-D array took 16 ms
    full walk of matrix as 2-D array-list took 15 ms
Testing 2D matrix of 500x1000: Test 4
    creating matrix as 2-D array took 45 ms
    creating matrix as 2-D array-list took 55 ms
    full walk of matrix as2-D array took 14 ms
    full walk of matrix as 2-D array-list took 15 ms
```

Comment: You're right, I should have specified that I am using an ArrayList specifically. Even though I'm thinking about it, I'm a little less concerned with how the code looks and a little more concerned with how it performs. I don't have a preference between an ArrayList and a 2D array, I'm just looking for performance. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: As with any performance question, you have to measure to be sure. Theoretically the array should be faster, but if you looped a 10K arrays vs 10K list inside a Spring controller, I'm pretty sure you would not be able to see a difference on the response-time, because the overwhelming IO latency. In my book readability/maintainability always wins over performance, at least until you start optimising.

Comment: @Klaus -- Good idea!  I add an anecdotal experiment to my answer.

Comment: @26hmkk -- You may want to write a similar test for your application scenario.